# Multiply values of same column with same id

Tags: sql

There is a table like this:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 0.55 |
| 1 | 0.4 |
| 3 | 0.6 |
| 1 | 0.4 |
| ... | ... |

I want to multiply Values where I have the same ID.

So that I get a table looking like this:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.032 |
| 2 | 0.55 |
| 1 | 0.032 |
| 3 | 0.6 |
| 1 | 0.032 |
| ... | ... |

Unfortunately I have no point where to start for this that makes sense...

Comment: *I want to multiply Values where I have the same ID*  what if there were 3 or more rows with ID=1?

Comment: @Stu this is possible and it makes the case difficult.

Comment: You don't mention this in your question or provide expected results where that's the case.

Comment: @Stu sorry, will edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a trick to doing that using [exp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/exp-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), `sum`, and [log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/log-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

```
select ID,  exp(sum(log(Value))) as Value
from t
group by ID
```

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.08 |
| 2 | 0.55 |
| 3 | 0.6 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d47400657a73ebb91a0462ffd1fa9416&hide=1)

Comment: Thank you. As an addition: In OracleSQL it is 'exp(sum(ln(Value))) as Value'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT id, (a.value * b.value) as sum
FROM tablename, tablename a
WHERE tablename.id = a.id
```

Comment: Please do not encourage [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Thank you, but this only works when an ID only appears 2 times. But I have some appearances n>2.